# Cascading with *this, returning a reference to a class constant

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding cascading using the `return *this` statement in C++. I am going through a textbook and I ran across a usage of cascading that I do not fully understand.

The following code is my own construction:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Time
  {
  public:
     Time( int = 0, int = 0 ); 
     Time & setHour( int );                 
     void print( void );
     Time & operator+=( int ); // Line in Question 

  private:
     int hour; 
     int minute; 
  };

  Time::Time(int hr, int mn)
  {
     hour = hr;
     minute = mn;
  }

  Time & Time::operator+=(int increment) // Line in Question
  {
    hour += increment;
    return *this;
  }

  Time & Time::setHour(int h)
  {
    hour = h;
    return *this;
  }

  void Time::print( void )
  {
     cout << "hour = " << hour << endl;
     cout << "minute = " << minute << endl;
  }

int main()
{
   cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
   Time t;
   (t+=3)+=4;
   t.print();
   int x = 4;
   (x+=4)+=5;
   cout << x << endl;
}
```

Notice that the `+=` operator can be "cascaded" in the same sense that I am "cascading" using the integer variable `x`. The text I am reading seems to suggest that the two lines in question, marked with comment `// Line in Question` should have the keyword `const` in front of Time. That is, the functions return a reference to a Time object constant. I don't see why this is true (or a case where this would make sense), since we are modifying the data member of Date.

What would be the purpose of having the keyword `const` in the beginning of the lines marked `// Line in Question` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the text says they *should* have a `const` in front? That would make it impossible to modify through the returned reference.

Comment: The text doesn't say it should, it in fact has the keyword const printed in the example that is given. The code is also accessible from the publisher's website with the same text. The writer is claiming cascading is enabled.

Comment: He might be referring to a different thing where the compiler will add 3 to a const version and then copy construct the const copy back to the original variable. Check that this is not what they mean. By const copy I mean temporaries that are created and assigned by the compiler behind the scenes. Maybe they mean something like that. I cannot tell since your example is not from the book so it is not meaning anything in that context.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the purpose of having the keyword const in the beginning of the lines marked // Line in Question ?

Returning a `const` reference from `operator +=` would have the effect of **preventing** the kind of cascading you are using in the `main()` function, such as:

```
(t+=3)+=4;
```

This would be prevented because `t+=3` would return a constant reference to a `Time` object, and since `operator +=` is not itself qualified as `const`, you would get a compilation error when trying to apply `+= 4` to the `const` reference returned by `t+=3` (you can't invoke a `const` member function on a non-`const` object).

I would expect the author of the book to comment on the reasons for preventing this. I personally don't see why it is harmful here.

Comment: Strangely, the const keyword is used and simultaneously, the authors claim cascading is enabled. In fact, this similar situation is repeated again with the assignment operator, operator=.

Comment: @jrand: Have you tried adding the `const` keyword? It should not even compile. Are you sure you're not overlooking something in the textbook?

Comment: Yes, the code does not compile with the const keyword. This may just be a syntax error.

Comment: @GManNickG: Deitel's C++ Programming, 8th edition. Their code compiles (from here: http://media.pearsoncmg.com/ph/esm/deitel/cpp_htp_8/code_examples/code_examples.html), I just don't see how I can perform cascading with the const keyword (or why).

Comment: @jrand: There's something like 26 zip files there. Which one is it?

Comment: @AndyProwl: ch11.zip, Folder Fig11_06_08, I had to add the line #include <stdexcept> to Date.cpp to compile under g++. I am looking at line 13 of fig11_08.cpp.

Comment: @jrand: But there is no cascading there, is there? I think you're misunderstanding the author's intention (or he is not clearly stating it). Adding `const` prevents cascading...